# Show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}f(x,y)$ does not exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $D=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus\{ (x,y):y=2x \}$ and let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by

$$
f(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)^2(y-2)}{2x-y}
$$
Show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,2)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

I am having trouble choosing a path to go along to prove that it does not exist. I have tried along the axes and along y=x, not sure what to do or how to go about this question.

EDIT: apologies, it is (1,2)

Comment: Is it $(x,y)\to(1,2)$ or $(x,y)\to(0,0)$? The title and the post say different stories.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 my apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question does not match the title. In the title you let $(x,y) \to (0,0)$. I am taking limit as $(x,y) \to (1,2)$ in this answer.

$f(1,2+\frac 1 n)=\frac {-2} {-\frac  1n} \to \infty$.

[For $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ you can take limit along the $x-$axis].

Answer for the modified version: Take limit along the path $(x-1)^{2}(y-2)=2x-y\equiv 2(x-1)-(y-2)$ or $y=2+\frac {2(x-1)} {1+(x-1)^{2}}$. The limit along this path is $1$ whereas the limit along  $x=1$ is $0$.

Comment: so sorry I seem to have forgotten the brackets around (y-2), not sure if this changes the answer because I am attempting it the way you said and not having luck

Comment: @JohnWarts I have included an answer for this modified question also.

Comment: please may I ask, how on earth did you think of the path to take???? it is a very long and complicated path, and I do not understand your solution

Comment: @JohnWarts Just working with straight lines through $(1,2)$ may not work. If the function has  a limit at the point then the limits have to be the same along all curves passing thrugh the point. Since the limit along $x=1$ is $0$ I wanted to see if there is a path along which the limit is not $0$. So I tried to take $f(x,y)=1$ and see if that gives  a path passing thorugh $(1,2)$. You don't have to know how this curve looks like.